# How do I configure the location of the Android NDK in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

Is the ${ndk.dir} value set as part of the PATH env variable in Windows, or is there a setting found somewhere in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup any (NDK in your situation) path environment in Windows - [here's](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) how can you do that.

In Eclipse you can add NDK builder in your project properties - see [this manual](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had my machine with Eclipse installed...but I remember searching for a while to find the same thing.  In the end it was under something like:

Preferences -> Android

(Not in the project properties)